# cannot access element within function in javascript custom object

Tags: javascript

When I run this code it generates the appropriate file upload ui and adds the event listener to the upload button.  However the first line in the upload function throws an error - Cannot read property 'style' of undefined - for this.missingFile.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
function FileUploader(props) {
    var div = document.querySelector(props.element);

    var uid = generateGuid();

    var templateHtml = "<p><div id=\"dvMissingFile-" + uid + "\" class=\"missing-file\"> Please choose a file.</div><input type=\"file\" id=\"flUploadedFile-" + uid + "\" name=\"flUploadedFile-" + uid + "\"/></p><div class=\"dvProgressBar\" id=\"progress-" + uid + "\"><div></div></div>";
    div.innerHTML = templateHtml;

    this.uploadButton = document.querySelector(props.uploadButton);
    this.fileInput = document.querySelector("#flUploadedFile-" + uid);
    this.missingFile = document.querySelector("#dvMissingFile-" + uid);
    this.progress = document.querySelector("#progress-" + uid);
    this.url = props.postUrl;

    this.upload = function() {
        this.missingFile.style.display = "none";

        if (this.fileInput.files.length === 0) {
            this.missingFile.style.display = "";
        }
        else {
            var file = this.fileInput.files[0];
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var pbar = document.querySelector("#progress-" + uid + ">div");
            if (xhr.upload) {

                // do upload
            }
        }
    }

    this.uploadButton.addEventListener("click", this.upload);
}
```

Usage example

```
<div id="dvUploader"></div>
<button type="button" id="btnUpload" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
<script>
var uploader = new FileUploader({
                    element: "#dvUploader",
                    uploadButton: "#btnUpload",
                    postUrl: "myposturl"
});
</script>
```

Comment: `this` within the function `upload` is not the same `this` as before. You can use fat arrow notation `this.upload = () => {}`

Comment: Or put the upload function on the prototype if you don't want to use fat arrows. Or use bind to explicitly set the this context of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small update to your code can help:

```
    this.upload = function() {
// ...
    }.bind(this);
```